# How do I clear 2D Vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector, stl

Can any one please suggest me, How do I clear 2D vector in C++. 
I have to write program where I need to read in Matrix , Process and Clear Matrix and get ready for next read operation. I have created 2D array with vector> I am filling  but failing to reset. Below is the code for reference.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>


using namespace std;


#define MAX 501
typedef std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec2d;
vec2d matrix(MAX , std::vector<int>(MAX, 0));

void main()
{
    int tc; 
    int N;

    for(tc =0 ; tc < 20;tc++)
    {
        int temp;
        scanf("%d",&N); 

        int result =0;

        for(int i = 0; i < N;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<N;j++)
            {               
                scanf("%d",&temp);
                matrix[i][j]=temp;
            }
        }
        // Do Some processing with 2D vectory Array 

        matrix.clear(); // Now I want to clear 2D vector but only vector contents, and get ready for new input reading  
                    // How do I do it with 2d Vector ? 
        cout << result << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you overwrite it, there is no need to reset value to `0` first.

Comment: I need to ask. If you're just going to reassign the values, why bother resetting them to 0?

Comment: It is required because matrix will not be completely filled but partially. So while processing need empty values as 0 or some other negative value. Though in above code I am doing scanf for entire array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An other alternative is:

```
matrix = vec2d(MAX , std::vector<int>(MAX, 0));
```

And to avoid the allocation each time, you may cache the value:

```
static const vec2d matrix_zero = vec2d(MAX , std::vector<int>(MAX, 0));
```

And each time you want to reset matrix:

```
matrix = matrix_zero;
```

Comment: Unfortunately less efficient as it will perform dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: Caching the value may be a little more efficient than simply allocating a new vector each time, but unfortunately it is not extensible as it will quickly get messy when the author decides he wants to fill with numbers other than 0.

Comment: Unfortunately you will end up with some useless data in memory forever now.

Comment: I feel this option looks better for me instead reiterating through entire array that is ( 501 x 501 items) everytime to clear

Comment: @Sandeep: Note that under the wood, it will do the loop or equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

Here are two ways in C++11:

```
std::for_each(matrix.begin(), matrix.end(), [](std::vector<int>& v)
{
    std::fill(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
});
```

or

```
for(auto& elem : matrix) std::fill(elem.begin(), elem.end(), 0);
```

You could also use a regular for loop like this:

```
for (size_t y = 0; y < matrix.size(); y++)
{
    for (size_t x = 0; x < matrix[y].size(); x++)
    {
        matrix[y][x] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: If we're talking about C++11, how about the **for range** `for(auto elem& : matrix) std:: fill(elem.begin(), elem.end(), 0);`?

Answer (score -2):

Sorry for the late here, actually I didn't know about coding back in 2014.
I have got a result,
I hope you can try with memset.

```
 memset(matrix,0,sizeof(matrix));
```