# How to read data form .CSV file using arrays instead of vectors in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I am trying to read the content of the .csv file using 1D_array instead of using 1D_vector, and 2D arrays instead of 2D vector. Below is my code of reading the .csv file using vector and its works correctly.
But my professor asked me to use arrays instead of vectors for further optimization issues. I have tried to use arrays but still can't get it.
Can anyone help please?

```
    //functoin to read dataset from .csv file.
bool read_data_set(string filename, vector<vector<int>>& vec_X_dataset, vector<int>& vec_Y_dataset) {
    int field0, field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6, field7, field8, field9, field10, field11,
        field12, field13, field14, field15, field16, field17, field18, field19, field20, field21;
    char comma;
    string line;
    ifstream myfile(filename);
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
       while (myfile
            >> field0 >> comma
            >> field1 >> comma
            >> field2 >> comma
            >> field3 >> comma
            >> field4 >> comma
            >> field5 >> comma
            >> field6 >> comma
            >> field7 >> comma
            >> field8 >> comma
            >> field9 >> comma
            >> field10 >> comma
            >> field11 >> comma
            >> field12 >> comma
            >> field13 >> comma
            >> field14 >> comma
            >> field15 >> comma
            >> field16 >> comma
            >> field17 >> comma
            >> field18 >> comma
            >> field19 >> comma
            >> field20 >> comma
            >> field21)
        {

       vector<int> inner_vec{ field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6, field7, field8, field9, field10, field11,
      field12, field13, field14, field15, field16, field17, field18, field19, field20 };
            vec_X_dataset.push_back(inner_vec);
            vec_Y_dataset.push_back(field21);

        }
       myfile.close();

    }
    else {
        cout << "Unable to open file";
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


int main() {

    cout << endl << "KNN  K-Nearest-Neighbors in C++" << endl << endl;
    cout << "please insert the value of K ";
    cin >> k;

    // Read dataset from file.
    string filename = ".//Cleaned Covid Dataset.csv";
    vector<vector<int>> vec_X_dataset{};
    vector<int> vec_Y_dataset{};
    bool error = read_data_set(filename, vec_X_dataset, vec_Y_dataset);
    if (error) {
        cout << "Exiting with error while reading dataset file " << filename << endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
```

bool read_data_set(string filename, int (&array_X_dataset)[5430][20], int (&array_Y_dataset)[5430]) {
int field0, field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6, field7, field8, field9, field10, field11,
field12, field13, field14, field15, field16, field17, field18, field19, field20, field21;
char comma;
string line;

```
ifstream myfile(filename);
if (myfile.is_open())
{
    while (myfile
        >> field0 >> comma
        >> field1 >> comma
        >> field2 >> comma
        >> field3 >> comma
        >> field4 >> comma
        >> field5 >> comma
        >> field6 >> comma
        >> field7 >> comma
        >> field8 >> comma
        >> field9 >> comma
        >> field10 >> comma
        >> field11 >> comma
        >> field12 >> comma
        >> field13 >> comma
        >> field14 >> comma
        >> field15 >> comma
        >> field16 >> comma
        >> field17 >> comma
        >> field18 >> comma
        >> field19 >> comma
        >> field20 >> comma
        >> field21)
    {


        /*vector<int> inner_vec{field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6, field7, field8, field9, field10, field11,
   field12, field13, field14, field15, field16, field17, field18, field19, field20 };
        vec_X_dataset.push_back(inner_vec);
        vec_Y_dataset.push_back(field21);*/
    
        cout << field21 << endl; 

         for (size_t i = 0; i < 5430; i++)
        {
            array_Y_dataset[i] = field21;
        }

      

    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 5430; i++)
    {
        cout<< i << " "<< array_Y_dataset[i] << endl;
    }
  myfile.close();
  
}
else {
    cout << "Unable to open file";
    return true;
}
return false;
```

}

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: I need to read the data from file using arrays instead of vectors, but I don't know how, can you please edit my code if you know the way of using arrays to read from file

Comment: Have you tried just replacing `vector` with `array`?

Comment: Try and just replace `vector` with `array`, see if you understand what's going on. If you have any issues, come and edit this question with the problems you have.

Comment: yes I tried, but its not working since arrays can't change its size during runtime

Comment: True, but that means you have to figure out how many items you have to store in the array. If your professor asked you to do that, that means that information is available somewhere, and then you use that value on your `array`. The code should still work the same, you just need to figure the amount of items.

Comment: yes I know the size of the array, when I tried to read the data from the file using the array and printout the content of the array, It store only the first element of the file, it doesn't store all the rows in the array one by one.

Comment: But do you understand why it does that?

Comment: Can you please try that on your computer, I can send you the file of the dataset, If you are welling to help me

Comment: How many elements are in your `array`? How many elements are in your file?

Comment: my file has 5430 rows and 20 columns, I gave the array size of [5430][20] .

Comment: Ok then update your question with the problem you're having now, and the new code you have. I'll take a look from there.

Comment: okay, I will try something and back to you

Comment: I have edited my code as you can see up in the code section, As you can see when I printout the content of array_Y_dataset, it printout the first element  of field21 to the whole array. Can you please tell me why

Comment: I think the problem is that I iterate through the array while the value of field21 is still the first element. But, how I can iterate through the array without for loop .

Comment: The first thing I see is that you got the returnvalue of your function wrong. It returns `false` on success and you treat that as an error. Generally, use exceptions, which allow you to even include a speaking error message. That said, please provide a [mcve], which obviously includes a minimal set of input data to reproduce the problem you hardcode the input into the code itself.

Comment: You need to correct the formatting. And please give the new information in your question as well, to make things clearer. `array_Y_dataset[i] = field21;` this will fill the entire array with the same value. Is that what you want?
I don't know how your professor taught arrays, but it would be much simpler to use `std::array`. It works like C-arrays, but has the same methods as `vector`.

Comment: Note that field21 is the last column of the dataset , so field21 size is [5430][1].

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (untested, but should work), I hope it helps you out:

```
bool read_data_set(string filename, array<array<int, 20>, 5430>& vec_X_dataset, array<int, 5430>& vec_Y_dataset) {
    int field0, field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6, field7, field8, field9, field10, field11,
        field12, field13, field14, field15, field16, field17, field18, field19, field20, field21;
    char comma;
    string line;
    ifstream myfile(filename);

    int line = 0;

    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
       while (myfile
            >> field0 >> comma
            >> field1 >> comma
            >> field2 >> comma
            >> field3 >> comma
            >> field4 >> comma
            >> field5 >> comma
            >> field6 >> comma
            >> field7 >> comma
            >> field8 >> comma
            >> field9 >> comma
            >> field10 >> comma
            >> field11 >> comma
            >> field12 >> comma
            >> field13 >> comma
            >> field14 >> comma
            >> field15 >> comma
            >> field16 >> comma
            >> field17 >> comma
            >> field18 >> comma
            >> field19 >> comma
            >> field20 >> comma
            >> field21)
        {

       array<int, 20> inner_vec{ field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6, field7, field8, field9, field10, field11,
      field12, field13, field14, field15, field16, field17, field18, field19, field20 };
            vec_X_dataset[line] = inner_vec;
            vec_Y_dataset[line] = filed21;
            line++;

        }
       myfile.close();

    }
    else {
        cout << "Unable to open file";
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Using `std::array` will make things clearer to read, and easier to manage in code. The main idea behind this, while with `std::vector` you're just pushing new values and it grows the way it needs (which if fine), if you know the size of the array beforehand, that means you know where in the array every piece of data will go.

Comment: array<int, 5430> inner_vec = {{field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6, field7, field8, field9, field10, field11,
           field12, field13, field14, field15, field16, field17, field18, field19, field20 } };

Comment: This line of your code give me an error says : "unitizer cannot convert from list to int "

Comment: You have too many `{`, it should be `{field1, field2, ...` not `{{field1, field2, ...`

Comment: okay I removed the extra braces and also I add #include<array>, thus the error is fixed. Thank you.

Comment: But, another error appeared in this line of code.   array_X_dataset[line] = inner_vec ;                 the error says " array type int [20] is not assignable "

Comment: Are you using `std::array`?

Comment: inner_vec : is std:: array

Comment: but array_X_dataset is a normal array as follow : int array_X_dataset [5430][20] ;

Comment: Right that's the issue. You can't assign  `std::array` and `[]`.
Do you have to use `int array_X_dataset [5430][20`?

Comment: I need to store the content of inner_vec in array_X_dataset , but array_X_dataset  is a two dimensional array.

Comment: what is your suggestion, do I need to create another std::array that is 2D ??

Comment: Yes, that's what I did, I think you missed it. I have `array<array<int, 20>, 5430>& vec_X_dataset`. You can create one in main too.

Comment: You can also do it all with C-arrays, but if you want to use both at the same time, the code will look different (because they're not the same types). I would suggest using `std::array` everywhere, it'll look cleaner, and will help you avoid bugs.

Comment: i will try and back to you.. thanks for your time, you are a great person

Comment: so when trying to create " array<array<int, 20>, 5430>& array_X_dataset  { } ; " in the main it gave me an error

Comment: but in the main its work for " array<int, 5430> array_Y_dataset{}; "

Comment: You want  `array<array<int, 20>, 5430> array_X_dataset { } ;` no `&`. '&' is a reference, so that you don't copy the array and can actually modify it in the function.

Comment: Opps, sorry I didn't even recognize the '&'... thanks a lot

Comment: Now, this line of code   ' array_X_dataset[line] = inner_array; ' gave me an error

Comment: how I could copy the content of 1D std::array which is inner_array into 2D std::array which is  array_X_dataset ????

Comment: What's your error? You're not copying to 2D array, your copying to one of the arrays in the 2D array (the one at position `line`).

Comment: ShadowMitia, I would like to thank you for your cooperation, the code runs correctly with your helpful comments.   Thank you again

Comment: @wala  No problem, glad I could help. Don't forget to mark the answer as solved! And don't worry, it's normal to struggle when you're learning.

Comment: I have a question:  Do you know how to clear the contents of 2D std::array

Comment: You should ask a new question since this problem is solved. That would be a completely different question. And it depends on what you're trying to do as well. You can start by looking here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26491003/how-do-i-clear-2d-vector-in-c

Answer (score 0):

After an interesting conversatoin with ShadowMitia, the problem was solved and bellow is the code after modifications.

```
bool read_data_set(string filename, array<array<int, 20>, 5430>& array_X_dataset, array<int, 5430>& array_Y_dataset) {
int field0, field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6, field7, field8, field9, field10, field11,
    field12, field13, field14, field15, field16, field17, field18, field19, field20, field21;
char comma;
int line = 0;
  
ifstream myfile(filename);

if (myfile.is_open())
{
    while (myfile
        >> field0 >> comma
        >> field1 >> comma
        >> field2 >> comma
        >> field3 >> comma
        >> field4 >> comma
        >> field5 >> comma
        >> field6 >> comma
        >> field7 >> comma
        >> field8 >> comma
        >> field9 >> comma
        >> field10 >> comma
        >> field11 >> comma
        >> field12 >> comma
        >> field13 >> comma
        >> field14 >> comma
        >> field15 >> comma
        >> field16 >> comma
        >> field17 >> comma
        >> field18 >> comma
        >> field19 >> comma
        >> field20 >> comma
        >> field21)
    {


     array<int, 20> inner_array{ field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6, field7, field8, field9, field10, field11,
     field12, field13, field14, field15, field16, field17, field18, field19, field20 };
        array_X_dataset[line] = inner_array; 
        array_Y_dataset[line] = field21;           
        line++;

    }
      
  myfile.close();
  
}
else {
    cout << "Unable to open file";
    return true;
}
return false;
```

}

int main() {

```
// Read dataset from file.
string filename = ".//Cleaned Covid Dataset.csv";

//int array_Y_dataset[5430] = {};
//int array_X_dataset[5430][20] = {};
array<array<int, 20>, 5430> array_X_dataset{}; 
array<int, 5430> array_Y_dataset{};
bool error = read_data_set(filename, array_X_dataset, array_Y_dataset);
if (error) {
    cout << "Exiting with error while reading dataset file " << filename << endl;
    exit(-1);
}
```

}